# Как умножить матрицу на вектор, используя mutex

Tags: c++

Как умножить матрицу на вектор, используя mutex на С++                                         Матрица и вектор заданы рандомно

Comment: Как открыть файл, используя шоколадную трубочку? Как приготовить борщ, если вы прочитали «Войну и мир»?

Comment: @alishka193, а зачем при этом умножении (если, конечно, результат это уже выделенный вектор) вообще Вам понадобился mutex?

Ведь каждый поток обрабатывает независимые данные (какие именно, можно передать в параметрах).

--

Судя по формулировки вопроса, не думаю, что речь идет об управлении пулом потоков-"умножителей".

Answer (score 1):

Например, как-то так:

```
mutex.lock();
try
{
    // вычисления
    mutex.unlock();   
}
catch(...)
{
    mutex.unlock();
    throw;
}
```

Comment: а где RAII?

Comment: @Free_ze: Зачем же вручную?

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        // вычисления
    }

Comment: @KoVadim
RAII сейчас нет, зайдите попозже)

@VladD
Считайте это псевдокодом, т.к. про реализацию ничего ТС не говорил. Стоило бы написать по мотивам C++11, как привели вы, но я с ним не знаком, каюсь)

Comment: Лучше так:
    
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        // вычисления
    }